# What is meant by 'Assignment Branch Condition Size too high' and how to fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-metrics, rubocop

In my Rails app, I use `Rubocop` to check for problems. Today it gave me an error like this : `Assignment Branch Condition size for show is too high`. Here's my code :

```
def show
  @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @categories = Category.all
  @search = @category.products.approved.order(updated_at: :desc).ransack(params[:q])
  @products = @search.result.page(params[:page]).per(50)
  rate
end
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: A brief search uncovers [this](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AbcMetric). It's a `rubocop`'s formal way of saying "your method does too much".

Comment: Are all of the defined variables be used in the rendering?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Assignment Branch Condition (ABC) size is a measurement of the size of a method.  It is essentially determined by counting the number of **A**ssignments, **B**ranches, and **C**onditional statements.   [(more detail..)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_score)

To reduce ABC score, you could move some of those assignments into before_action calls:

```
before_action :fetch_current_category, only: [:show,:edit,:update] 
before_action :fetch_categories, only: [:show,:edit,:update] 
before_action :fetch_search_results, only: [:show,:edit,:update] #or whatever

def show
  rate
end

private

def fetch_current_category
  @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:id])
end

def fetch_categories
  @categories = Category.all
end

def fetch_search_results
  @search = category.products.approved.order(updated_at: :desc).ransack(params[:q])
  @products = @search.result.page(params[:page]).per(50)
end
```

Comment: Great thanks. Now the code looks a lot readable but isn't it making the file large? More code? Is it good?

Comment: Less code if you need those variables in other actions.

Comment: I am getting the same on this method:
    # Draw the ball into this device context
      def draw(dc)
        dc.setForeground(color)
        dc.fillArc(x, y, w, h, 0, 64 * 90)
        dc.fillArc(x, y, w, h, 64 * 90, 64 * 180)
        dc.fillArc(x, y, w, h, 64 * 180, 64 * 270)
        dc.fillArc(x, y, w, h, 64 * 270, 64 * 360)
      end

I don't seem to be able to preserve the code block layout here!!!
What is going on here? There are no assignments, no branches, and no conditionals here at all!!!!

Comment: You have assignments implicit where you're multiplying the numbers.  I'd take them and move them to constants so you're not re-evaluating the same arithmetic in those calls.  I'm not sure if this will fix your linter's feedback but it would certainly clean it up a tiny bit. :)

Comment: You could assign them all in one line like: `RQ,RH,RT,RW=[90,180,270,360].map { |i| i * 64 }`

Comment: i can see this work for cases you'd use instance objects,  but for those that don't how do you solve high ABC ?

Comment: Generally it's a matter of properly abstracting your objects and considering the interface you're presenting.   It's a pretty vague question you've asked, but given an example project I could present some ideas for refactoring away the complexity of your classes.  Sorry I can't give a more concrete suggestion without a more concrete example.