# What is 'Assignment Branch Condition Size too high' and how to fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubocop, code-metrics

In my Rails app, I tried to run Rubocop to check for problems.
It gave me an error like this : **Assignment Branch Condition size for show is too high**. Here's my code :

```
def create
    @field = Api::AnalyticsQueryBuilderMetadataService::Field.create(field_params, { type: 'fields' })
    if @field['message'].nil?
      redirect_to fields_index_path(entityId: field_params[:entityId], entity_name: field_params[:entity_name], schemaId: field_params[:schemaId],
                                    schemaMnemonic: field_params[:schemaMnemonic], schemaName: field_params[:schemaName])
    else
      flash[:notice] = @field
      redirect_to new_field_path(entityId: field_params[:entityId], entity_name: field_params[:entity_name], schemaId: field_params[:schemaId],
                                 schemaMnemonic: field_params[:schemaMnemonic], schemaName: field_params[:schemaName])
    end
  end
```

How to solve such error, this error is not affecting the user, but during Zenkin build, it fails, How to solve it.

Comment: Can you show the exact error? What library does this pop out of in the stack trace?

Comment: you can refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30942788

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Assignment Branch Condition Size too high' is a [linting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) error, produced by a tool performing static code analysis. It indicates that there are too many assignments, branches and conditionals in one method or function.

It is not an *error* in the sense that it will cause incorrect behavior when your code runs, rather it's a sign that your code is overly complex and may eventually suffer from maintainability issues.

You fix the error by refactoring your code, so that there are fewer assignments, branches and conditionals in the same method, *or* by ignoring the issue for code you believe is already optimal.